# inline-block to span tag behaves differently in IE and webkit-browsers

Tags: css, html

`display:inline-block`  to `span` tag behaves differently in various browsers. In IE browsers it works perfectly. But in webkit-browers(Chrome, Safari, etc..), there is a little  gap between `span` and its child tag.
*Here is the sample code:*

```
     <style>
       span{
         display:inline-block;
         border:1px solid red;
         padding:0px;
         margin:0px;
        }
     </style>

      <span>
          <input type="text"/>
       </span>
```

*Output in different browers* 
**IE** 
[image]

**Chrome and Safari**
[image]

See there is gap between spand and input field...

Comment: `input` may have margin by default on webkit engine. try to remove the margins. `input {  margin:0; }`

Comment: Got it...set margin:0px; to input tag instead of span.

Comment: @CanGeliş just now I realized that... anyways thanks  for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this selector, because margin is between span and input, not just span, so you need to target `input` element and not `span` element

```
span input {
    margin:0px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNFB7/1/)